# How to get access to parameter of object, created in one daemon-like script from another daemon-like script

Tags: php, multithreading, worker

I'm trying to write gameserver based on [Workerman](http://www.workerman.net/en/).

Main idea is: list of workers accept messages from clients and puts them to the queue (RabbitMQ), another group of workers get messages from queue, do some calculation and update GameWorld instance accordingly.

GameWorld instance itself is created on start of the main process, workers are created after creating of the GameWorld object. So, I wrote dummy class Server:

```
namespace Server;
use \Workerman\Worker;
use \Workerman\Lib\Timer;

class Server {

    private $name;

    public function setName(string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function printName(){
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

Also I wrote two simple workers just for testing concept of updating object from different workers.

First (`start_worker1.php`):

```
use \Workerman\Worker;
use \Workerman\Lib\Timer;
use \Server\Server;

global $ws_worker;

$ws_worker = new Worker('Websocket://0.0.0.0:8000');
$ws_worker->name = 'FirstWorker';
$ws_worker->onWorkerStart = function($ws_worker)
{
    $ws_worker->server = new Server();
    $ws_worker->server->setName("FirstName");
    echo "worker1 started\n";
    $ws_worker->is_started = TRUE;
    var_dump($ws_worker);  
};
```

Here I created new Server object and give it a name, also changed property `$ws_worker->is_started` to TRUE (default value is False).

Second(`start_worker2.php`):

```
use \Workerman\Worker;
use \Workerman\Lib\Timer;

global $ws_worker;

$worker = new Worker('Websocket://0.0.0.0:8001');
$worker->name = 'SecondWorker';

// here I'm checking, if I had an object of the first worker
// and actually it outputs all the data about first worker object,
// but $ws_worker->server is NULL and $ws_worker->is_started = FALSE
// This is confusing me so much..

var_dump($ws_worker);

// here I'm trying to detect when first worker is started
// but it return false all the time..

while(!$ws_worker->is_started){
    var_dump($ws_worker->is_started);
    sleep(1);
}
$worker->onWorkerStart = function() use($ws_worker){

    echo "worker2 started\n";
    var_dump($ws_worker);
    $ws_worker->sever->setName("NewName");
};
```

Here I created second worker and tried to access `server` property of the first worker object, but with no success..

All this stuff is started this way:

```
use Workerman\Worker;
use Server\Server;

if(strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS), 'win') === 0)
{
    exit("start.php does not support windows, please use     start_for_win.bat\n");
}

if(!extension_loaded('pcntl'))
{
    exit("Error! <pcntl> extension not found! Please install pcntl extension.");
}

if(!extension_loaded('posix'))
{
    exit("Error! <posix> extension not found! Please install posix extension.");
}

define('GLOBAL_START', 1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

require_once __DIR__ . '/start_worker1.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/start_worker2.php';

// Run all services
Worker::runAll();
```

I guess that in worker2 I can access an worker1 object before function `$ws_worker->onWorkerStart` is evaluated, but I have no idea, how to access worker1 object in real time ( I mean - get access to current state of the object).

I'm new to PHP OOP style programming, I should say. So please show me where is my mistake. Detailed explanation greatly appreciated.